# Selecting pandas dataframe rows depending on other rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe with a few thousand rows and multiple columns, one of which contains IDs (integers) and one that contains dates (python datetime objects). Different rows can have identical IDs and/or dates+time. I would like to add a boolean column to the dataframe which indicates for each row if the dataframe contains another row that has an identical ID AND has a date+time that is within 2 months of - BUT NOT identical to - the date of the row itself.

See below for some example data where the "Boolean condition" column is filled correctly.

| index | ID | Date | Boolean condition |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20000242 | 2021-06-18 09:46:13.433 | True |
| 2 | 20000242 | 2021-06-18 09:46:13.433 | True |
| 3 | 20000242 | 2021-07-16 11:41:49.557 | True |
| 4 | 20000242 | 2021-08-13 13:36:30.417 | True |
| 5 | 20103342 | 2018-10-19 11:10:45.817 | False |
| 6 | 20103657 | 2019-09-13 10:18:00.173 | True |
| 7 | 20103657 | 2019-09-13 10:18:00.173 | True |
| 8 | 20103657 | 2019-09-13 12:16:53.737 | True |
| 9 | 20103657 | 2019-10-04 14:24:41.067 | True |
| 10 | 20103657 | 2020-03-03 13:50:32.953 | False |
| 11 | 20103657 | 2020-03-03 13:50:32.953 | False |
| 12 | 20103657 | 2020-03-03 13:50:32.953 | False |
| 13 | 20103657 | 2020-03-03 13:50:32.953 | False |
| 14 | 20103657 | 2020-03-03 13:50:32.953 | False |
| 15 | 20105037 | 2020-12-18 15:48:09.187 | False |
| 16 | 20201854 | 2021-03-05 14:49:11.850 | True |
| 17 | 20201854 | 2021-04-02 14:07:50.213 | True |
| 18 | 20201854 | 2021-05-28 08:35:57.363 | True |
| 19 | 20201854 | 2021-05-28 08:35:57.363 | True |
| 20 | 20203290 | 2020-02-07 11:13:08.117 | False |
| 21 | 20203290 | 2020-02-07 11:13:08.117 | False |
| 22 | 20203290 | 2020-02-07 11:13:08.117 | False |
| 23 | 20203290 | 2020-02-07 11:13:08.117 | False |
| 24 | 20203290 | 2020-02-07 11:13:08.117 | False |
| 25 | 20203290 | 2020-02-07 11:13:08.117 | False |
| 26 | 20401499 | 2018-07-13 11:10:02.960 | True |
| 27 | 20401499 | 2018-07-13 11:10:02.960 | True |
| 28 | 20401499 | 2018-07-13 13:46:52.483 | True |
| 29 | 20401499 | 2018-07-13 13:46:52.483 | True |
| 30 | 20402860 | 2019-12-13 11:18:31.253 | False |

I've tried to accomplish this naively with nested loops, but this is not feasible for thousands of rows.

Does anybody know a more efficient / pythonic way to do this?

EDIT: Here is the same data in semi-colon separated values:

index;ID;Date;Boolean condition

1;20000242;2021-06-18 09:46:13.433;True

2;20000242;2021-06-18 09:46:13.433;True

3;20000242;2021-07-16 11:41:49.557;True

4;20000242;2021-08-13 13:36:30.417;True

5;20103342;2018-10-19 11:10:45.817;False

6;20103657;2019-09-13 10:18:00.173;True

7;20103657;2019-09-13 10:18:00.173;True

8;20103657;2019-09-13 12:16:53.737;True

9;20103657;2019-10-04 14:24:41.067;True

10;20103657;2020-03-03 13:50:32.953;False

11;20103657;2020-03-03 13:50:32.953;False

12;20103657;2020-03-03 13:50:32.953;False

13;20103657;2020-03-03 13:50:32.953;False

14;20103657;2020-03-03 13:50:32.953;False

15;20105037;2020-12-18 15:48:09.187;False

16;20201854;2021-03-05 14:49:11.850;True

17;20201854;2021-04-02 14:07:50.213;True

18;20201854;2021-05-28 08:35:57.363;True

19;20201854;2021-05-28 08:35:57.363;True

20;20203290;2020-02-07 11:13:08.117;False

21;20203290;2020-02-07 11:13:08.117;False

22;20203290;2020-02-07 11:13:08.117;False

23;20203290;2020-02-07 11:13:08.117;False

24;20203290;2020-02-07 11:13:08.117;False

25;20203290;2020-02-07 11:13:08.117;False

26;20401499;2018-07-13 11:10:02.960;True

27;20401499;2018-07-13 11:10:02.960;True

28;20401499;2018-07-13 13:46:52.483;True

29;20401499;2018-07-13 13:46:52.483;True

30;20402860;2019-12-13 11:18:31.253;False

Answer (score 3):

[Pandas indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) is clearer and more efficient than nested loops:

```
df_duplicated = df[df['ID'].duplicated() == True] # duplicated IDs

another_column_in_range = []

for index,row in df_duplicated.iterrows(): # Iterate over rows
  df_id,df_date = row['ID'],row['Date']

  catch_df = df_duplicated[df_duplicated['Date'] - df_date < timedelta(days=60)] # Generate a df with the rows that match the condition

  if catch_df.empy: # If catch_df is empty, the condition didn't match any row
    another_column_in_range.append(False)
  else:
    another_column_in_range.append(True)

df_duplicated["another_column_in_range"] = another_column_in_range

final_catch = []
for index in len(df):
    if df[index]['ID'] in df_duplicated:
        if df[index]['ID']["another_column_in_range"] == True:
           final_catch.append(True)
           break
    final_catch.append(False)

df["another_column_in_range"] = final_catch
```

Comment: It almost works, but not completely because df and df_duplicated are not the same length...

Comment: Solved, but not tested. If you don't post the data frame with an easily copy pastable format, I can't test my code.

Comment: I've edited my question by adding the data as semi-colon separated values which you can save to a .txt file and load using df = pd.read_csv('df_example.txt', sep=";")